# Sourcetree - How I can delete Https Saved Password

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to delete my old saved account from Sourcetree.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to delete, see. link below.

https://ctrlv.cz/D4fJ

We tried to delete the files in the local AppData, according to the instructions here on the forum, but it also doesn't work.

Please, give me an advice.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To Windows, close SourceTree and type `Credential` on search bar from Taskbar. Select item `Windows Credentials`. It will opens `Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager`

Select icon `Windows Credentials` and you can see all saved passwords. Search SourceTree saved password and delete it.

[image: Example to delete SourceTree password]

Open SourceTree and wala! Password deleted

References:

- https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-7-credential-manager-windows-vault
- https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Cannot-delete-an-account-on-sourcetree/qaq-p/602672